# How to track user interactions from Sitecore Mobile SDK

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, mobile

Does Sitecore Mobile SDK for Sitecore version 8.x support collecting analytics data to be saved into the xDB.

From some article they mentioned it is difficult to achieve analytics from Sitecore Mobile SDK because of the limitations in the architecture of XDB, then what are the difficulties and what is the out of the box ideas which can be used to track users interactions?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to track user with Sitecore Mobile SDK. You have to use Sitecore universal tracker but before that you will have to migrate to Sitecore9.1. Universal tracker works with Sitecore 9.1+ versions only